# Difference between Expression Vs TERR vs Iron python in Spotfire

Tags: spotfire

In Spotfire when to use **custom Expression, TERR Scripts and Iron python scripts**, also which works best in most of the scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

They are quite different.

The **Custom Expression** is remarkably useful to filter data using SQL-like expressions.

The **TERR Scripts** allows you to add R scripts to your code.

The **IronPython** scripts can be used to MANY things on your code. From colouring the visualisations, getting (or setting) Document Property values, showing message boxes to the users and so on.